# Crazyhouse chess KoTH

Tags: king-of-the-hill, chess, javascript

### What is Crazyhouse Chess?

[Crazyhouse Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazyhouse) is a chess variant that is basically normal chess except you can place a piece you previously captured back on the board instead of a regular turn.

### Bot interface

Only JavaScript bots are allowed.
A bot is a JavaScript function that takes 3 arguments (board, side, bank) and returns a move.
The function should also have a property `n` for the name of the bot.

The board argument is an array of 64 characters, each representing a square on the chess board. If the character is uppercase, it represents a white piece.

```
'-' - empty square
'K', 'k' - king
'N', 'n' - knight
'R', 'r' - rook
'Q', 'q' - queen
'B', 'b' - bishop
'P', 'p' - pawn
```

The side argument is a number (1 - you are playing white, 2 - you are playing black)

The bank argument is a dictionary:
`{"p": 0, "n": 0, "b": 0, "r": 0, "q": 0}`
The numbers represent the count of pieces you have.

#### Move return format

A move is an array with two elements. If the move is a normal move, then the array contains the from square and to square. If the move is a piece place, the first argument is the piece char (always lowercase) and the second argument is the destination square.

Example bot:

```js
var bot = (board, side, bank) => {
   const move = (side == 1) ? [52, 36 /* e2e4 */] : [12, 28 /* e7e5 */]

   return move;
}
bot.n = "BotName"
```

Note: If a bot returns an invalid move, it counts as a resignation - the bot loses the game.

### Chess simplifications

1. En passant is not allowed.
2. Castling is not allowed
3. Leaving the king in check is allowed, the objective of the game is to capture the king, not checkmate

### The controller

If you find any bugs feel free to point them out.

```js
var abot = (board, side, bank) => {
    const move = (side == 1) ? [52, 36 /* e2e4 */] : [12, 28 /* e7e5 */]; // side 1 = white 2 = black

    return move;
}
abot.n = "TestBot";

var bots = [abot, abot]
var rating = new Array(bots.length).fill(0);

function pair() {
    var ret = []

    for (var x = 0; x < bots.length; x++) {
        for (var y = x + 1; y < bots.length; y++) {
            ret.push([x, y])
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

const startpos = [
 'r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r',
 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p',
 '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
 '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
 '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
 '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P',
 'R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R',
];

function rank(sq) {
    if (sq < 0 || sq > 63) return -1;
    return 8 - Math.floor(sq / 8);
}

function file(sq) {
    if (sq < 0 || sq > 63) return "-";
    return "abcdefgh"[sq % 8];
}

function piece_color(piece) {
    if (piece == '-') return 0;

    if (piece == piece.toUpperCase()) return 1; // white

    return 2; // black
}

const knight_moves = [
    17, 15, 10, 6,
    -17, -15, -10, -6
];

const king_moves = [
    1, 8, 9, 7,
    -1, -8, -9, -7
];

const pawn_cap = [
    9, 7
];

const rook_moves = [
    8, 1, -8, -1
];

const bishop_moves = [
    9, 7, -9, -7
];

function canrookmove(board, sq1, sq2) {
    var sq;
    if (file(sq1) == file(sq2)) {
        const f = file(sq1);
        for (const move of rook_moves) {
            sq = sq1;
            while (true) {
                sq += move;
                if (file(sq) != f || piece_color(board[sq]) == piece_color(board[sq1])) break;
                if (sq == sq2) return true;
                if (board[sq] != '-') break;
            }
        }
    } else if (rank(sq1) == rank(sq2)) {
        const r = rank(sq1);
        for (const move of rook_moves) {
            sq = sq1;
            while (true) {
                sq += move;
                if (rank(sq) != r || piece_color(board[sq]) == piece_color(board[sq1])) break;
                if (sq == sq2) return true;
                if (board[sq] != '-') break;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function canbishopmove(board, sq1, sq2) {
    var sq;
    for (const move of bishop_moves) {
        sq = sq1;
        while (true) {
            sq += move;

            if (piece_color(board[sq]) == piece_color(board[sq1])) break;

            if (sq == sq2) return true;

            if (board[sq] != '-' || rank(sq) == 1 || rank(sq) == 8 || file(sq) == 'a' || file(sq) == 'h' /* edge of the board */) break;
        }
    }
}

// return: 0 - draw; 1 - white won; 2 - black won
// the game is automatically a draw after 200 moves
function play(w, b) {
    var board = [...startpos];

    var moves = 0;

    var wbank = {'p': 0, 'n': 0, 'b': 0, 'r': 0, 'q': 0};
    var bbank = {'p': 0, 'n': 0, 'b': 0, 'r': 0, 'q': 0};

    while (true) {
        var move = bots[w](board, 1, wbank);
        if (!checkm(board, move, 1, wbank)) return 2;

        if (typeof move[0] == "string") {
            wbank[move[0]]--;
            board[move[1]] = move[0].toUpperCase();
        } else {
            if (board[move[1]] == 'k') return 1;
            if (board[move[1]] != '-') wbank[board[move[1]]]++;
            board[move[1]] = board[move[0]];
            board[move[0]] = '-';
        }

        move = bots[b](board, 2, bbank);
        if (!checkm(board, move, 2, bbank)) return 1;

        if (typeof move[0] == "string") {
            bbank[move[0]]--;
            board[move[1]] = move[0];
        } else {
            if (board[move[1]] == 'K') return 2;
            if (board[move[1]] != '-') wbank[board[move[1]].toUpperCase()]++;
            board[move[1]] = board[move[0]];
            board[move[0]] = '-';
        }

        if (++moves == 200) return 0;
    }
}

function play_wrapper(white, black) {
    const result = play(white, black);

    console.log(bots[white].n, 'vs', bots[black].n, '-', ['draw', `white (${bots[white].n})`, `black (${bots[black].n})`][result])

    if (result == 1) {
        rating[white] += 3;
        rating[black] -= 1;
    } else if (result == 2) {
        rating[black] += 3;
        rating[white] -= 1;
    }
}

function run() {
    const games = pair();
    var result;

    for (const game of games) {
        play_wrapper(game[0], game[1]);
        play_wrapper(game[1], game[0]);
    }

    console.log("Ratings:")
    for (var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++) {
        console.log(bots[i].n, rating[i])
    }
}

run();

// check legality of a move
function checkm(board, move, side, bank) {
    if (typeof move[0] == "string") {
        if (move[1] > 63 || !("pnbrq".includes(move[0]))) return false;

        if (move[0] == 'p' && [1, 8].includes(rank(move[1]))) return false; // pawns can't be placed on rank 1 and 8
        if (board[move[1]] != '-') return false;

        if (bank[move[0]] == 0) return false;
    } else {
        if (move[0] > 63 || move[1] > 63 || piece_color(board[move[1]]) == side || piece_color(board[move[0]]) != side) return false;

        switch (board[move[0]]) {
            case '-':
                return false;
            case 'N':
            case 'n':
                return knight_moves.includes(move[1] - move[0]);
            case 'K':
            case 'k':
                return king_moves.includes(move[1] - move[0]);
            case 'P':
                if ((move[1] - move[0]) >= 0) return false;
                if ((move[0] - move[1]) % 8 != 0) { // capture
                    if (board[move[1]] == '-') return false;

                    return pawn_cap.includes(move[0] - move[1])
                } else {
                    if (board[move[1]] != '-') return false;
                    if ((move[0] - move[1]) / 8 == 2) return (rank(move[0]) == 2);

                    return ((move[0] - move[1]) / 8) == 1;
                }
            case 'p':
                if ((move[0] - move[1]) >= 0) return false;
                if ((move[1] - move[0]) % 8 != 0) { // capture
                    if (board[move[1]] == '-') return false;

                    return pawn_cap.includes(move[1] - move[0])
                } else {
                    if (board[move[1]] != '-') return false;

                    if ((move[1] - move[0]) / 8 == 2) return (rank(move[0]) == 7);

                    return ((move[1] - move[0]) / 8) == 1;
                }
            case 'R':
            case 'r':
                return canrookmove(board, move[0], move[1]);
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                return canbishopmove(board, move[0], move[1]);
            case 'Q':
            case 'q':
                return canrookmove(board, move[0], move[1]) || canbishopmove(board, move[0], move[1]);
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Edit

Edit: Updated controller and added support for bot names

Comment: You mention a move is a pair of two values, a `from` and `to` index/position on the board. But how do we move a chess piece from the bank back into play instead, since this is specifically the crazyhouse chess variant?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen i covered that in the post. If you want to place a piece the first element of the array is the character representing that piece and the second element is the square

Comment: @Philx0 Ah, you're completely right, I glossed over that sentence (here for anyone else that's blind like me.. ;) "If the move is a piece place, the first argument is the piece char (always lowercase) and the second argument is the destination square."). My bad.

Comment: FYI, this probably isn't gonna get many submissions, as even this simplified chess is a complicated game

Comment: <del>You know, it is crazy since two pawns in one column (二歩) is allowed, and also checkmate by place a pawn into the board (打ち歩詰め).</del>

Comment: `canbishopmove` errors on the first white bishop move. (it calls `piece_color(board[sq])` but `sq` is off the board, which causes `board[sq]` to be undefined)